# Unable to run my app on iOS 13. For a framework problem

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, crash

I'm trying to test my project on my iPhone with iOS 13, using Xcode 12 beta 6.

The app crash on start and this is the message in the log:

dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/system/introspection
DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Developer/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Developer/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GPUTools.framework/libglInterpose.dylib:/usr/lib/libMTLCapture.dylib:/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib
(lldb)

Someone can help me?
Thank you

Comment: have you found solution for this crash?

Answer (score 12):

This occurs because Xcode fails to sign the frameworks that are provided by SwiftPM with your app’s signing identity. It’s a known issue (SR-13343) in Xcode 12.

You can do these steps on third framework file to try fix :

1. select:Siging & Capabilites.
2. find : FrameWorks, Libraries, and Embedded Content.
3. change : the. "embed" of the third frameworks from "Do not Embed" to "Embed & Sign".

Comment: It is now located in Project Navigator -> ProjectName -> Targets -> ProjectName -> General -> Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content (Just scroll down)

Answer (score 2):

Go to Project Settings -> Target -> General -> Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content -> Check that your custom framework has "Embed & Sign" option

Answer (score 0):

add AppTrackingTransparency.framework to your project

Comment: Ok I'll try it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I made a SPM framework and embedded then occurred this error.

I unchecked "Copy only when installing" in Build Phase of Embed Frameworks then works fine

you can also check this
[Stripe iOS SDK via Swift Package Manager is installing, but crashing because "Library not loaded"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63977172/stripe-ios-sdk-via-swift-package-manager-is-installing-but-crashing-because-li)

Answer (score 0):

Don't Copy the Framework directly to your project. Adding 'Embed Pods Frameworks' manually works for me. Try It.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking permission for tracking via `AppTrackingTransparency`, you must add`NSUserTrackingUsageDescription` key to the info plist.