# Unable to run my app on physical device or simulator Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm trying to launch my app and it directly crashes when I run. The error message is this one:

```
2021-12-06 21:17:29.830742+0100 WeSo[8090:2720663] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FIRInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Document path cannot be empty.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x180f6104c 0x1995d5f54 0x1035c7504 0x1035c6a18 0x1035e6730 0x1035f3f38 0x100847528 0x100847264 0x1008b3b88 0x1892f1aa8 0x1008b3ab8 0x1008b3e98 0x188dcbf7c 0x188957680 0x188bd3990 0x1889660d8 0x1889acd28 0x1b28fc9a4 0x1b28fc3ac 0x1b28fd11c 0x1b28facd0 0x1889a33fc 0x1889499f0 0x1889acd28 0x1b28fc9a4 0x1b28fc3ac 0x1b28fd11c 0x1b28facd0 0x188bd6cd8 0x188a12448 0x188a2e0c4 0x1b28fc9a4 0x1b28fc3ac 0x1b28fab0c 0x1b28fad1c 0x188ba8e8c 0x188a26860 0x188a7b724 0x188a666c0 0x1836c74a0 0x1839c8400 0x1836c9c80 0x1836090b4 0x192a58e20 0x192a7ecdc 0x192a396b4 0x192a3acf4 0x10164e3b4 0x101651e70 0x192a3af94 0x192a3a3d4 0x192a3e9e4 0x180f83020 0x180f93ce0 0x180ece054 0x180ed37f4 0x180ee73b8 0x19c87738c 0x1838876a8 0x1836067f4 0x188b4a258 0x188a78534 0x188a59cb4 0x1008b3e14 0x1008b5d98 0x100da1a24)
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
dyld4 config: DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/system/introspection DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Developer/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Developer/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FIRInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Document path cannot be empty.'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I'm using Firebase with Pods, specifically Firestore, Messages, and Auth.
I tried the solution from this [Unable to run my app on iOS 13. For a framework problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63726726/unable-to-run-my-app-on-ios-13-for-a-framework-problem), but it didn't work, it wasn't able to install the app.

I also deleted all the Pod files and started the project all over, including a new Firebase.

I have to use Pods because I'm using the `pod 'GeoFire', :git => 'https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc.git'` module and I can't use it installing as a framework.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: try updating the pods

Comment: @loremipsum I keep getting the same error after updating pods

Comment: Maybe downgrade. If you set the version number you can use the previous version. Another way would be to try SPM. It seems to work per this post https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc/issues/157

Comment: can you accept the answer? It is the green checkmark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try downgrading to the previous version or using the Swift Package Manager.

According to this git link it should work
https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc/issues/157

I suggest you also submit a bug report to the pods creator. Provide as much information as you can so they can resolve it for the next person.